# Index 38 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 38 - Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am facing this error with the `Naive Bayes's` `CategoricalNB` algorithm

It gives the above error after the **2nd attempt** I run the cells. That means it works without any errors during the 1st time and when I try to change something (as small as a comment) and run the notebook again, it gives the error:

> IndexError: index 38 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 38

I don't know what is going wrong and how to fix. When I restart the kernel and try again it works and every attempt after the **1st attempt** it fails and gives the above error.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv("hr_dataset.csv")
# dataframe = pd.read_csv("WA_Fn-UseC_-HR-Employee-Attrition.csv")

dataframe.head(2)
```

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import CategoricalNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# inputs = scaled_df
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs, target, test_size=0.2)

categoricalNB_ = CategoricalNB()


categoricalNB_.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape
```

```
pred = categoricalNB_.predict(X_test) # --------------> gives the error for every attempt after the 1st attempt. weird
```

```
categoricalNB_.score(X_test, y_test)
# accuracy_score(y_test,pred)
```

Comment: Array indices start from 0, so that if it has `n` elements, valid (positive) indices are from 0 to n - 1 (included).

Comment: So what are your suggestions @norok2 ? How can I solve this error?

Comment: And why does it work for the first attempt but not the afterwards?

Comment: Inspect that your arrays do have the correct shapes.

Comment: Yes, they have correct shapes, both `X_train` and `X_test` has equal rows and so is `X_test` and `y_test`

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you further, unless you provide enough information to reproduce your issue (i.e. either a copy of `"hr_dataset.csv"` or a minimal dataset showing the problem). See also [here](/help/mcve).

Comment: @norok2 here's my dataset: You can find it here. `https://drive.google.com/open?id=19gWVwuXS3my9C77D9unG53tuivPzZdqJ`

Comment: maybe you have other code which changes `X_test` after line which makes problem and when you run it again then it uses different `X_test`. You should check what you have in `X_test` before line which makes problem. At least check `shape`. But if you check values in `X_test` then maybe you will see why it is different.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your issue is related to having a different set of values for a feature in the train, and feature set.

I went through your database, and found that you have only one record, where the total working years is 38. If that record is only accessible in the test set, then your fit from the training set will not contain a probability for the value 38 thus throwing an out of bounds error.

You could either solve this with class_prior parameter ([for more details read docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.CategoricalNB.html)), or you could make sure, that you have for every feature every category at least a certain amount of record.

Comment: I can corroborate this hypothesis. The cause is because `CategoricalNB` expects a certain number of classes in the feature vectors during training and testing. The `train_test_split` function does not guarantee this, so during training the model sees some number of input categories, but in testing it sees some other number of categories (or a category it hasn't seen before in the train set). Because of this, the model throws an error (index out of bound).

Comment: Additionally, this issue can be solved by telling `CategoricalNB` in advance, how many categories to expect, with the parameter `min_categories`. If you are using pandas, this can be done easily using the `nunique` method:
`CategoricalNB(min_categories=df.nunique())`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set some value to **min_categories**, it helped me

```
model = CategoricalNB(min_categories=10)
```

For your data it may differ from 10

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty albeit quick hack to this issue is to perform the following before the train/test split,

```py
c = 10
data[:,i:j] = c * np.round(data[:,i:j] / c)
```

This just round all the feature columns (`i`th to the `j`th (non-inclusive)) towards the nearest multiple of `c` which in this case is 10. Now your columns are less unique and you are less likely to encounter a test data point that is not present in the training set.

Of-course this assumes that the column range is integral however someone can tweak this for real values as well. This may also fluctuate your model's performance.